# How to style radio button inside alert dialog in android?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I would like to change the text color of radio buttons inside a dialog, and other attributes as well. How to do?

The code I used to create radio buttons inside dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);            
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(someArray, -1, someListener);
```

I have tried ***new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)***, it works only on dialog itself, not work on embedded radio buttons(say text color).

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));            
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(someArray, -1, someListener);
```

***R.style.AlertDialogCustom*** example: (tried other attributes as well, none works)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorGray</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/colorGray</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButton</item>
</style>
</resources>
```